# formula bar maximum length

Tags: vba, excel

I am having problem with excel formula bar when formula exceeds 1024 characters.
It is not accepting formula and giving "out of memory" run time error when i am setting the formula from vb6 code.

Are there any settings in excel to increase the maximum length of a formula bar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Excel version are you talking about?

Comment: @Deele,i am referring to excel 2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Excel 2003 the maximum number of characters in a cell is 32,767, all of
> which will show up in the formula bar, but only 1024 will show up in the cell
> itself.
>
> And that 1024 "limit" can be broken by adding alt-enters every 80-100
> characters, too.

Comment: One addition: I've met this problem with a formula containing a lot of external references with long filenames (>1100 chars total). Cleaning the links resulted in a much less verbose formula, so problem solved here.

Comment: @Scorchio: In addition to "cleaning the links", if the linked file is closed, simply open it (if possible) - then the path is removed from the formula. And if the file name is long, replace it with something short... :-)